# How do folder name localizations work?

Tags: osx, directory, gui, directory-structure, locale

In Mac OS X, there are directories like `Desktop`, `Users` and `Library`.

On localized systems, these would be named `Skrivbord`, `Användare` and `Bibliotek` (Swedish)

But when I am in the terminal I can't type, for example: `sudo mv ~/Skrivbord ~/Bibliotek`, but instead I have to type their actual names like this: `sudo mv ~/Desktop ~/Library`.

How can its name in the GUI be in whatever language but in the Terminal it's in English?

Comment: Choose Fedora, choose life! On my fathers Fedora 20, he has it in Icelandic locale, and I type Skjáborð(Desktop) in the terminal, no problem.

Comment: Ah, does fedora use symlinks you think?

Comment: I'm still a newbie, so I'm not sure what you mean, but if you mean does Fedora have symlinks then yes. Here are two examples: [Here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PackagingDrafts/Symlinks) and my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162987/unrar-multiple-parts/163051#163051) I use symbolic links.

Comment: It was my comment that was bad, no problems. What i meant was, Maybe fedora has a symlink named Skjáboro in the same directory as the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Finder is built in objective-c it uses nib localizations. Here is an example.

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/Resources/sv.lproj/ServicesMenu.strings
```

`sv.lproj` stands for `Svenska.localized project`

Here is the contents of `ServicesMenu.strings`

```
bplist00”[Finder/Open]Finder/Reveal_Finder/Show InfolFinder/÷ppna_Finder/Visa i Finder_Finder/Visa info i Finder)<Ulà
```