# Unrar multiple parts

Tags: fedora, zip

I need to unrar a file consisting of multiple parts.
The folder structure looks like this:

```
file.part01.rar
file.part02.rar
file.part03.rar
```

I've installed p7zip. When I try:

```
7z e file.part01.rar
```

I get the following error:

```
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: file.part01.rar

Error: Can not open file as archive
```

These files are definitely not corrupted, I can unrar them on Windows.

I'm using Fedora 20 and the newest version of [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/).

### Update

```
file file.part01.rar
file.part01.rar: RAR archive data, v1d, flags: Archive volume, os: Win32
```

---

```
7z e

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)


Error:
Incorrect command line
```

---

I'm using the newst version of p7zip, I've installed it today.
When I try to install unrar, I get this:

```
sudo yum install unrar
[sudo] password for user: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
No package unrar available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: Did you check integerity of your file such as md5 or sha?Sound like file damage.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: No, these files are definitely not corrupted, I can unrar them on Windows.

Comment: So i guess your comprossor and decomprossor dont version compatiable, use a newer, install `unrar` or upgrade `p7zip`.

Comment: What does "file *.rar" tell you? Have you tried simply "7z e" or "7z e ." without specifying filenames? It's possible you have pieces of a larger RAR file.

Comment: @barrycarter: Please see my updates.

Comment: Try "7z e ." or installing unrar from source: http://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-3.9.1.tar.gz

Comment: @user1170330 I get the exact same error with this: `7z e myfile1.splitted.rar`

Answer (score 6):

Now we've got the CLI tool `unar`.

```
$ repoquery unar -i

Name        : unar
Version     : 1.8.1
Release     : 5.fc21
Architecture: x86_64
Size        : 4768283
Packager    : Fedora Project
Group       : Unspecified
URL         : http://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline
License     : LGPLv2+
Repository  : fedora
Summary     : Multi-format extractor
Source      : unar-1.8.1-5.fc21.src.rpm
Description :
The command-line utilities lsar and unar are capable of listing and extracting
files respectively in several formats including RARv3. unar can serve as a free
and open source replacement of unrar.
```

To use it:

```
$ unar <rar part file>
```

Answer (score 5):

I get the exact same error when running 7zip on a rar file in multiple parts, I can't help you with that, but I suggest you use rar or unrar.

Solution:

Download `rar` from [here](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm).

Then do:

```
tar xzvf /pathtofile/rarlinux-x64-5.1.1.tar.gz
ln -s /pathtofile/rar/rar /usr/bin/rar
ln -s /pathtofile/rar/unrar /usr/bin/unrar
```

The command to decompress with `unrar` is:

```
unrar x filename.part1.rar
```

or `rar`

```
rar x filename.part1.rar
```

Make sure all the files are in the current directory.

Sample output:

```
Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r36

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r37

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r38

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r39

...         myfile1                                                      

Extracting from myfile1.splitted.r40

...         myfile1                                                   OK 
All OK
```

I'm using `Fedora` 21, and `yum` gives me `unrar` with `rpmfusion-nonfree` enabled:

```
root ~ # yum list unrar
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * fedora: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * livna: rpm.livna.org
 * rpmfusion-free-rawhide: ftp.astral.ro
 * rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide: ftp.astral.ro
 * updates: ftp.astral.ro
 * updates-testing: fr2.rpmfind.net
Installed Packages
unrar.x86_64              5.0.12-3.fc21               @rpmfusion-nonfree-rawhide
```

To enable `rpmfusion`:

Fedora 14 to the most current:

```
su -c 'yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://download1.rpmfusion.org/free/fedora/rpmfusion-free-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm http://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/rpmfusion-nonfree-release-$(rpm -E %fedora).noarch.rpm'
```

then

```
yum update
yum install unrar
```

`rpmfusion` can be found [here](http://rpmfusion.org/).

Comment: yes this works! I tried the unrar-free and that did not worked. it created inner files as directories

Answer (score 3):

```
unar file.part01.rar
```

It works automatic with multiple parts rar archives in Raspbian

Comment: Yes, you just unrar the first file, it finds the rest as long as they're all in the same directory.  You can add an -x but that's the default action anyway, to extract.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a job for rar2fs

I never tried Fedora so I went to google and it took me to the link below at fedora wiki and there I can not see rar2fs listed:

```
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/User:Peter/FUSE
```

So let us install it from source then, you need unrar and fuse for this

#### Install on Linux!

```
git clone https://github.com/hasse69/rar2fs.git /tmp/rar2fs
wget -q http://www.rarlab.com/rar/unrarsrc-5.4.5.tar.gz -P /tmp/rar2fs/
tar -zxf /tmp/rar2fs/unrarsrc-5.4.5.tar.gz -C  /tmp/rar2fs
make -j$(($(nproc)+1)) -l$(($(nproc)+2)) -C  /tmp/rar2fs/unrar
make install-lib -C  /tmp/rar2fs/unrar
autoreconf -f -i /tmp/rar2fs/unrar
cd /tmp/rar2fs/; ./configure --with-unrar-lib=/tmp/rar2fs/unrar
make -j$(($(nproc)+1)) -l$(($(nproc)+2)) -C  /tmp/rar2fs
make install -C  /tmp/rar2fs
rm -rf /tmp/rar2fs
```

Thats it, now just mount your rar dirs, change them after your needs:

###### Mount:

```
mkdir ~/rar2fs
rar2fs -o allow_other ~/downloads ~/rar2fs
```

###### Unmount:

```
fusermount -u ~/rar2fs
```

###### Automount:

```
printf '\n%s\n' \ 
"### autmount for rar2fs" "rar2fs#~/downloads ~/rar2fs
fuse allow_other,--seek-length=1    0 0"
```

#### Gentoo:

```
emerge --ask rar2fs
```