# Fedora: unrar creates huge binary files after extracting rar5 files

Tags: fedora, rar

I'm running Fedora 35 and I'd need to extract a rar archive which contains log files (text).
When using **unrar**, as a result a huge list of binary files are created:

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 francesco francesco 94568930677013 Sep 10 09:36 log10.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 francesco francesco 94568938371590 Sep 10 09:36 log11.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 francesco francesco 94568940015859 Sep 10 09:36 log12.log
-rw-rw-r--. 1 francesco francesco 94568937104517 Sep 10 09:36 log13.log
. . . . . .
```

Much the same result, when extracting from the Desktop (Cinnamon).
This problem only happens on this OS (Fedora 35). When using a Windows machine I'm able to extract it.

An user of this forum mentioned as workaround to use xextractor. However, I cannot see it available in Fedora default repos.
Do you have any advice for that?

Edit: I've tried using a Java program to unrar files and I get the following error which might be the explanation:

```
exception.UnsupportedRarV5Exception
```

I've updated the question accordingly

Comment: You could try `p7zip`, which is available in the repos.

Comment: Try using this https://www.rarlab.com/rar/rarlinux-x64-612.tar.gz

Comment: Thanks! it worked!

Comment: @Carla Would you provide an answer below so a future user might be able to implement the same solution?

Comment: @Carla related to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162987/unrar-multiple-parts/